# GeoCoding Google Maps Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

In the below code when I stop the code in **FireBug**, the "results" object is a nice array filled with **good geocoded values**.

However, the **locations[]** array I put it into is full of all "**undefined**" values.

Shouldn't that be impossible because I can see the **results[0]** each time working nicely?

```
 var locations = [];

    function makeCallback(addressIndex) {
        var geocodeCallBack = function (results, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                locations[addressIndex] = results[0];
            }
        };
        return geocodeCallBack;
    }

    $(function() {
        for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
            $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=' + addresses[x], null, makeCallback(x));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After line:

```
var geocodeCallBack = function (results, status) {
```

`results` is object with properties `results, success`, for example `Object {results: Array[1], status: "OK"}` so the line:

```
locations[addressIndex] = results[0];
```

has to be changed to

```
locations[addressIndex] = results.results[0];
```